# If (Months.Columns(1).Value = "Oct" Or "Jan" Or "Apr" Or "Jul") Then ---- Type mismatch how do i fix?

Tags: excel, vba

I amd trying to do

```
If (Months.Columns(1).Value = "Oct" Or "Jan" Or "Apr" Or "Jul") Then
```

but there is type mismatch. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: That is not how the `Or` operator works.

Comment: You can't compare an entire column to a `String` either.

Comment: so what would you do instead? its only 1 cell in the column though

Comment: Then just reference the cell directly.

Comment: Vote to reopen as the cited answer covers only 50% of the issues. The type mismatch error will result from the wrong use of `.Columns.Value`, too and doesn't seem to have been asked expressly at SO. Furthermore reopening would allow to demonstrate some interesting code variations as well as a hint to omit the outer brackets of the `If` condition :-)

Answer (score 5):

That's not how the `Or` operator works. Each item must have a complete boolean comparison:

```
If Months.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Oct" Or Months.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Jan" Then
  ' Do something 
End If
```

If you want the shorthand, use a `Select Case` instead:

```
Select Case Months.Cells(1, 1).Value 
  Case "Oct", "Jan", "Apr", "Jul"
    ' Do something
  Case Else
    ' Do something else or do nothing
End Select
```

<sub>Updated the column reference to a cell reference.</sub>

<sub>Also, I'm assuming that `Months` is a worksheet code name or some other worksheet object.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

**Logical syntax issues**

Think you are running into issues trying to get the value of an entire row (range) instead of referencing a well defined cell therein, e.g. the first one via `.Cell(1)` or via `.Cell(i)` in a possible loop referring to an index or row index (e.g. `i`).

Besides the fact that you use a *wrong syntax logic* combining a *boolean* result with strings *(~> typical type mismatch* as mentioned already by braX), you could shorten the code as follows:

```
If InStr("OctJanAprJul", Months.Columns(1).Cells(1).Value) Then '...
```

C.f. [MS Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.columns)

*Further hint* You needn't include the `If` condition in brackets here as you did in your original posting.

*(Side note: By any means avoid to pass variables in brackets as arguments to a sub procedure, as this tries to evaluate the argument with possibly unwanted effects, e.g. changing a defined `ByRef` argument to a `ByVal` argument)*